# Conky ignore everything but main monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, conky

I am using the [qlocktwo](http://mowgli-writes.deviantart.com/art/qlocktwo-conky-470067388) conky theme which works great when I just have my main monitor connected, but when I add a second monitor for a dual monitor setup, the widget display isn't where I want it. I would like it to display in the center of my main monitor, but with a second monitor to the right of my main monitor, the conky widget displays in the top right corner of my main monitor.

So is there some way of fixing this, like making conky ignore the second monitor?

For reference my config file is below.

```
background no
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_class Conky
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
alignment mm
gap_x 0
#575
gap_y 0
#310
use_xft yes
xftfont Source Sans Pro:size=18
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 15.0
uppercase yes
double_buffer yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
draw_shades yes
default_shade_color 000000
default_color ffffff
color1 2d2d2d
#2d2d2d
#4A2B45
#382536
#3F2E2F
#000000
TEXT
${alignc}${color}I T ${color1}L ${color}I S ${color1}A S T I M E
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 35}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 15}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 20}${color}${endif}${endif}A ${color1}C ${if_match   ${exec date +"%M"} >= 15}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 20}${color}${endif}${endif}Q U A R T E R ${color1}D C
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 20}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 30}${color}${endif}${endif}T W E N T Y ${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 25}${if_match   ${exec date +"%M"} < 30}${color}${endif}${else}${color1}${endif}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 5}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 10}${color}${endif}${endif}F I V  E ${color1}X
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 30}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 35}${color}${endif}${endif}H A L F ${color1}B ${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >=          10}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 15}${color}${endif}${endif}T E N ${color1}F T O
${alignc}${else}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 45}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 50}${color}${endif}${endif}A ${color1}C ${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >=         45}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 50}${color}${endif}${endif}Q U A R T E R ${color1}D C
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 35}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 45}${color}${endif}${endif}T W E N T Y ${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 40}${if_match    ${exec date +"%M"} >= 35}${color}${endif}${else}${color1}${endif}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 55}${color}${endif}F I V E ${color1}X
${alignc}H A L F B ${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 50}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 55}${color}${endif}${endif}T E N ${color1}F ${color}T O${color1}
${alignc}${endif}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 35}${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} >= 5}${color}${endif}${endif}P A S T ${color1}E R U ${if_match ${exec date +"%M"}  < 35}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 9}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}N I N E
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 1}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}O N E ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 6}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}S I X           ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 3}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}T H R E E
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 4}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}F O U R ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 5}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}F I V E       ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 2}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}T W O
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 8}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}E I G H T ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 11}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}E L E V E N
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 7}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}S E V E N ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 12}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}T W E L V E
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 10}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}T E N ${else}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 8}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}N I N E
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 12}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}O N E ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 5}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}S I X          ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 2}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}T H R E E
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 3}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}F O U R ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 4}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}F I V E       ${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 1}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}T W O
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 7}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}E I G H T${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 10}${color}${else}${color1}${endif} E L E V E N
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 6}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}S E V E N${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 11}${color}${else}${color1}${endif} T W E L V E
${alignc}${if_match ${exec date +"%I"} == 9}${color}${else}${color1}${endif}T E N ${endif}${color1}S E ${if_match ${exec date +"%M"} < 5}${color}${endif}O C L O C K
```

Comment: As a short term fix hold the alt key down, left click on conky window and drag it where you want it. Works for me at least. What is the display resolution of your main monitor?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Cool I didn't know you could use the alt key to move the widget. And my main monitor has a resolution of 1680x1050.

Comment: Is the main monitor to left, right, top or bottom of the external monitor in your virtual desktop setup?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the main monitor is to the left of the external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Term Solution

You can hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and left click on the Conky window then drag it to where you want it.

## Long Term Solution

Your conky alignment is set to `mm` which translates into "middle-middle". When you have one monitor active at 1680x1050 this works fine. The top left corner of your "Talking Clock" is positioned around pixel column number 500 row column number 300. It's hard to judge looking at the code.

When you have two monitors active, and the second monitor is 1024x768 it expands the virtual desktop to 2704x1050 and now `mm` translates to near the right border of the main monitor (around column 1100).

The solution is to set the alignment to the top-left of the main monitor and adjust the x & y gaps. Remove these lines from your Conky resource file:

```
alignment mm
gap_x 0
#575
gap_y 0
#310
```

Now add these lines:

```
alignment tl
gap_x 500
gap_y 300
```

Save the file (but don't exit) and conky will immediately repaint on your screen. Keep adjusting `gap_x` and `gap_y` until perfectly centered. You might want to have your editor opened on your second monitor to speed the editing process up. Begin working in large gaps of +/- 100 then reduce to +/- 50... {25, 12, 6, 3, 1} to fine tune the position.